# SSL Cipher Suite version from HTTP ETW logs

Tags: asp.net, ssl, etw

I am trying to set up HTTP.SYS ETW traces from [Event Tracing in HTTP.sys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/wndp/event-tracing-in-http-sys-part-1-capturing-a-trace) to capture the TLS/Cipher Suites data for my web server. When I look at the CSV or XML traces, I see a bunch of events related to the SSL handshake:

[image]

However, I don't find things like TLS Version, Cipher Suite, Exchange Strength, etc. Is it not available in ETW Traces? I could not find any useful documentation around this.

Comment: TLS data can be found with Microsoft-Windows-WebIO provider

Comment: @magicandre1981 Can you please share any relevant documentation as to how can I decode the payload? I see things like: `"EnabledProtocols": 2720, "CipherConfig": 0, "CredHandleHigh": 1916664895168,"CredHandleLow": 1588831776064,`, but what do these mean?

Comment: I used Perfview to search for web related providers. Look if you can generate [parsers with this tool](https://github.com/microsoft/perfview/tree/main/src/TraceParserGen) that you can use with TraceEvent